# Google Docs brings Firefox to a grinding halt

Tags: google-sheets, firefox, google-sheets-performance

I've found recently that when I open a not-too-large* spreadsheet in Google Docs, within about 5 minutes of leaving it in a background tab, Firefox starts hogging 100% processor time. Closing the main Google Docs tabs and the spreadsheet tab makes it go back to normal. Is this a common problem with Firefox, or is it a problem with my extensions (eg: Firebug)?

*10-15 sheets, each of which has only a couple of dozen of rows max. No graphs or anything complicated.

Comment: Me too, from Early July 2019. was fine for me in June. Same spreadsheet 1000-2000 cells of data, 4 sheets. Now take about 75 seconds to change sheet tab.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your issue is with Firebug.  Whenever I have Firebug enabled Gmail and Google Docs run very slow.  In general I get a warning for this from Google.  Check out the fix document here http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=180248&topic=15176&hl=en. Note once you follow their suggested fix without turning firebug off you will still get a message from Google stating you have Firebug running.

Also, did you check to make sure you are running the latest version of Google Docs?  In the upper right hand corner next to your name there is a link that will either say Old Version or New Version.  If the link says Old Version then you are using the new version.  The older version of Google Docs was a but slower especially with larger documents.

Comment: Yeah I'm using the new version. I'll check out that link and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Yeah, didn't work. After about 5 minutes it just maxes out the processor even with all Firebug panels disabled. I'll try disabling the extension altogether.